# what's the difference between folders 'installedApps' and 'applications' in websphere application server?

Tags: websphere

Normally, after we create profiles both DMGR and Node, we have folder **applications** under path $DMGRPROFILE_HOME/config/cells/$cellName and **installedApps** under path $NODEPROFILE_HOME/. 
All the applications to be deployed will be put into folder **installedApps**. And we can also see the same contents under the folder **applications** above. So my question is what's the difference between them? why does the websphere application server put such apps into folder **applications** besides **installedApps**?
what's more, for example, if i need to update one file named web.xml of my deployed application war file, do i have to update file under both path above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `applications` path under the Dmgr profile contains the files that have been deployed in the admin console.

The `installedApps` path under the Node profile contains those files after they've been synchronized out to each node. In most cases, this will be immediately after the deployment as well.

### Deploying a single file

The safest practice would be to deploy a single file using the admin console, rather than editing it in-place on the filesystem:

[image]

The downside is that you have to enter the *entire* path to the server-deployed file name. e.g. `webapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/yourcompany/project/package1/YourClass.class`.

If you have a typo, it will deploy, but not where you wanted, and you might not notice it until your expected changes didn't take effect.

### Direct edit on the filesystem

That said, it is faster to edit on the filesystem, so we do that at times especially for like JSPs. To do that, you need to edit the copy under the Node's `installedApps` directory. (The location is controlled by WebSphere variable `APP_INSTALL_ROOT`, which defaults to `${USER_INSTALL_ROOT}/installedApps`.)

### web.xml

`web.xml`, however, is different. If you edit that in `installedApps`, the changes won't take effect. Instead, you'll need to edit the one in a path something like:

`$NODEPROFILE_HOME/config/cells/cellName/applications/earName.ear/deployments/applicationName/warName.war/WEB-INF`

Or do it in the $DMGRPROFILE_HOME and then synchronize the node (either through syncNode.sh or through the admin console).

Either way, you'll then need to restart the enterprise application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, dbreaux. But according to the reply above, i've got new questions here:

Comment: Thanks for your answer, dbreaux. But according to the reply above, i've got new questions here: 1. as for the web.xml update, you said either through NDDEPROFILE or DMGRPROFILE PATH is fine. but i tried and failed when edited under NODEPROFILE PATH, it's gonna be changed back to the DMGRPROFILE PATH version because of the NODE sync from DMGR. 2. why is not to work for file web.xml update from `installedApps` directly? and it's fine with jsp file update. @dbreaux

Comment: Another question is what's the folder `applications` under `NODEPROFILE` PATH for? obviously, for the one under `DMGRPROFILE`, it's for storing app deployed through admin console. and for `installedApps`, it's sync app from DMGR `applications`. and the websphere server java process would load app code from the `installedApps` when get running. @dbreaux

Comment: 1. Yes, if you edit under node and then sync, it will be overwritten. 2. I don't know why web.xml can't be edited in installedApps. I just know it can't.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what each of the different paths are for, just what I've discovered they do in these cases.