# How can I patch/copy java classes to local WebSphere server?

Tags: java, build, websphere, javacompiler

I am using WebSphere 8.5 for an Java/J2EE application development. Every time when I update java classes, I need to go through the process of building the EAR project, then updating the EAR filing through WebSphere console to deploy the changes. Is there an simple and quick process to patch/copy the java classes to WebSphere?

I have done it when I was developing application in Tomcat, I will just set build automatically in my IDE(eclipse) and it does the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy individual class files if you want to. Either officially, through the web console, or unofficially on the filesystem.

See [what's the difference between folders 'installedApps' and 'applications' in websphere application server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851276/whats-the-difference-between-folders-installedapps-and-applications-in-webs)

But I don't think this is what you're really seeking.

I don't know of any way to automatically update classes from an IDE to a remote WebSphere instance. I've only done so to a local WebSphere instance I run from within Rational Application Developer (IBM's branded Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks, now I understood how to deploy only file(s) to WebSphere  instead of an EAR. How did you automatically update classes in your local WebSphere instance from RAD?

Comment: That's too large a topic for a comment. But the gist is that you define a Server inside RAD and add Enterprise Projects to it. Then your project edits get automatically deployed to the server.

Comment: Note that directly updating the file system is likely not officially supported, and it is likely to cause problems if you add or remove Java EE annotations, annotated classes/methods/fields, or implementations of relevant interfaces (e.g., those referenced by `@HandlesTypes`).